# How can I show that $m(\Gamma(f))=0$ where $\Gamma(f)$ is the graph of $f$?

Tags: measure-theory

I have $f:\mathbb R\longrightarrow \mathbb R$ a measurable function and let denote $\Gamma(f)$ it's graph in $\mathbb R^2$. How can I show that $m(\Gamma(f))=0$ ?

I did as following : If $f=1_A$ for a measurable $A$, then $\Gamma(f)=A\times \{1\}\cup A^c\times \{0\}$ and thus, $m(\Gamma(f))=0$. I did the same when $f$ is simple, measurable positive and finally measurable. In fact, it's not complicate but a little bit long. Is there an other method ?

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/63284/lebesgue-measure-of-the-graph-of-a-function

Answer (score 1):

Your approche is good (and it's the common to solve this type of problem). Nevertherless, you have an other (more tricky) way. Let $V_k^n=[\frac{k}{2^n},\frac{k+1}{2^{n}}]$ which is measurable. Set $B_k^n=f^{-1}(V_k^n)\times V_k^n$ which is measurable. Then $G_n\bigcup_{k\in\mathbb Z}B_k^n$ is measurable (countable union of measurable set), and thus, $$\Gamma(f)=\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N}G_n,$$
is also measurable. Using Fubini-Tonelli, we get,
$$m(\Gamma(f))=\int \boldsymbol1_{\Gamma(f)}\mathrm d x\mathrm d y\underset{Fubini}{=}\int\underbrace{\left(\int\boldsymbol 1^x_{\{f(x)\}}\mathrm d y\right)}_{=m(\{f(x)\})=0}\mathrm d x=0.$$

*Notice that that for $E=\{(x,y)\mid ...\}$, we denote $E^x=\{y\mid ...\}$ (i.e. we fix $x$).*

Comment: It's a very complicate way for me, and I don't know if it's very optimal compare to the proof I proposed. But it's elegant anyway :) (+1)

Comment: Isn't there a simple way using Fubini-Tonelli directly ? $m^2(\Gamma(f)) = \int_{\mathbb R \times \mathbb R} \mathbf 1[f(x)=y] m(dx)m(dy) = \int _{\mathbb R}m(dx) \int_{\mathbb R} 1[f(x)=y]m(dy) = \int _{\mathbb R}m(\{f(x)\}) m(dx) =   \int _{\mathbb R}0 m(dx) = 0$ works for every non-atomic sigma-finite measure.

Comment: @justt: I imagine you mean $m^2(\Gamma(f))=\int_{\mathbb R\times \mathbb R}\boldsymbol 1_{\{(x,y=f(x))\mid x\in \mathbb R\}}m(dx)m(dy)$ Then by fubini this is $\int m(dx)\int \boldsymbol 1_{\{y=f(x)\}}^xm(dy)$ and then you conclude. But all the problem (to use fubini), is to show that $\Gamma(f)$ is measurable ! (that's why I made the first part).

Comment: For that you can claim that $\Gamma(f)$ is the preimage of the measurable set $\{0\}$ by the measurable function $(x,y)\mapsto f(x)-y$.

Comment: And yes, i use the widespread (and neat) convention $\mathbf 1[\text{equation}(\zeta)]$ for $\mathbf 1_{\{\zeta : \zeta\text{ verifies equation}\}}(\zeta)$.